# How can I bind a ListBox's Visibility to an ApplicationBar button?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I would like the toggle the visibility of a ListBox by tapping on a button an ApplicationBar.

I created the ApplicationBar[s] using [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394036%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). So their methods live in `App.xaml.cs`. The ListBox is in MainPage.xaml.

I don't understand how I can access the ListBox from App.xaml.cs, and what I could find suggested that this is not the best practice.

I got the sense that I should somehow bind the ListBox's visibility to the button.

Is that possible? If not, what should my approach be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the applicationbar in your page and apply a event on your button. In this event, change the visibility of your listbox.

To create a ApplicationBar, this tutorial is better (the msot basic) :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394040(v=vs.92).aspx

**EDIT (comments)** : You can bind a value from your VM to your Listbox (visibility) and change this value in App.xaml.cs ;)

Comment: The problem is I have need the `ApplicationBar` to have different items depending on which `PivotItem` is in selected. So I needed to use more than one `ApplicationBar`, which is why I used the tutorial that puts them in `App.xaml`.

Comment: Well, yes, I'm trying to. I only heard the term recently, so I don't know for sure if everything I'm doing is correct, but the materials I'm using are based around MVVM.

Comment: So, you can bind a value from your VM to your Listbox (visibility) and change this value in App.xaml.cs

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm still new to this, took a while to figure out how to make sense of your last comment, but it helped. Would you mind updating your answer?